# Проблема с SetTimeout: функция выполняется без задержки

Tags: javascript

Скрипт выполняет функцию без задержки, в чём ошибка?

```
<script>
    function nummain(num) {
        document.write('подожди ' + num + ' секунд ');
        num = num - 1;
        if (num == 0) {
            main(1);
        } else {
            document.setTimeout(nummain(num), 1000);
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    nummain(30)
</script>
```

Comment: @Noise, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве аргументов функции setTimeout используются функция и задержка. Вы же указываете не функцию, а её результат, т.н. рекурсия. Отсюда и появляется выполнение без задержки. Попробуйте так:

```
function nummain(num){     
    document.write('подожди '+num+' секунд ');     
    num = num-1;     
    if(num == 0) main(1);    
    else setTimeout( function() { nummain(num); }, 1000);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Не надо писать document. перед setTimeout

2) Вызываемую функцию надо передать как строку, проще говоря, обернуть в кавычки

```
setTimeout("nummain("+num+")",1000);
```

Comment: передавать строку в `setTimeout` - ужасная практика!

Comment: @Spectre Быть может, не силен в JS. Только поясните плз, почему это "ужасная практика" и как правильно?

Comment: когда вы передаёте строку - вы вызываете `eval`, правильнее передавать или анонимную функцию либо именованую, в которой идёт вызов данной

Comment: то, что вы написали практически эквивалентно 

    setTimeout(function() {
      eval( "nummain("+num+")" );
    }, 1000)

1 из правильных вариантов описан ниже

Comment: Если вас не беспокоит безопасность - напишите тесты простой анимации с активным использованием описанного вами подхода, везде протестируйте (и не забудьте какое-то там IE7 для большего эффекта) и вы сразу-же все поймете